# Orchard Breadcrumb Menu Placement

Tags: orchardcms, breadcrumbs

I have a site (1.9.2) that is using the built-in breadcrumb menu widget (display as breadcrumb option).

I have created an alternate for my custom content type (Product) and I need to display the breadcrumb between 2 zones declared in my Product alternate (Content-Product.Detail.cshtml).

As it's a widget, I can only place it in the top-level zones e.g. Content / BeforeContent.

Is there any way to control the positioning of the widget to so that it can be manipulated in my alternate?

Or is there a better way to implement a breadcrumb than using the menu widget?

Any help would be great.

Thanks